# Как изменить переменную в зависимости от разрешения экрана? stylus

Tags: css, css3, stylus

Использую *stylus*.
Есть переменная `$font-size = 1em`, которая используется везде по проекту.
Нужно, чтобы на мелких девайсах (`@media screen and (max-device-width: 768px)`), `$font-size` поменялся на `2em`. 
Попробовала использовать `if`, не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы слишком многого хотите от препроцессоров. Насколько мне известно, такое их поведение не регламентировано правилами. Желаемого вами поведения можно добиться при помощи *custom properties*:

```css
:root {
  --fz: 2em;
}
    
.block {
  font-size: var(--fz);
}
    
@media (max-width: 700px) {
   :root {
    --fz: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">This is text</div>
```

При помощи препроцессоров надо создавать миксины с нужными вам свойствам, передавать в них переменные, а в медиа-выражениях вызывать миксины заново с новыми значениями переменных, чтобы переопределить свойства. Например так:

```
my-custom-block(fz)
  border-radius 5px
  border 1px solid
  font-size fz
  margin fz

my-custom-block(2em)

@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
  my-custom-block(1em)
```

Comment: сработало! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ЛиндаЛи только обратите внимание, что поддержка браузерами custom properties пока что не самая радужная, это скорее будущее. но может быть есть хорошие полифиллы, не знаю.

Comment: В любом случае, буду все тестировать. Пока на моем телефоне работает, так что спасибо)

Comment: Кроссбраузерность плачет по этому варианту реализации :) Надеюсь в будущем...

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то в можно так:

В `head` прописать:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

А в *CSS* применять стили через media:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  elem {font-size: 1em;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  elem {font-size: 2em;}
}
```

Comment: у меня эта переменная используется во многих местах, поэтому хотелось бы в одном месте ее поменять, а не для каждого элемента прописывать. Иначе вообще теряется смысл переменных

Comment: @ЛиндаЛи, а нельзя через родителей? Указать шрифт одному родителю и через него применять шрифт к дочерним?

Comment: Oбщий родитель body

Comment: @ЛиндаЛи, или можно через специальный класс. К примеру, можно создать класс `font-default`